# Strange Tableview scrolling behavior

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got two views, each of which contains a tableview. They are identical in every respect except the height. They are each fed data from the same entity (currently filled with gibberish) in my Core Data store.

One of them works perfectly when scrolled, the other behaves differently. The problem is that the cells scroll past the top section header. Succeeding section titles bump older ones up as expected, and the header title slides up along with the cells.

Here are a couple of screenshots that I hope will illustrate the issue:

First, the one that works properly:

[image]

"A" is the top section header, and the cells don't scroll past it.

The next two shots are of the tableview that's behaving weirdly. I've added some arrows to show what's happening:

[image]

[image]

I've compared the settings in the Attributes Inspector, and unless I've overlooked something, they appear identical.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's the code from the associated UIViewController which is the delegate and the datasource for the TableView:

```
//
//  AvsAViewController.m
//  WMDGx
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 2/6/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AvsAViewController.h"

@interface AvsAViewController ()
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *frc;
}

@end

@implementation AvsAViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self refreshData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[frc sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configure the cell to show the activity's name
    ListActivity *thisActivity = [frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisActivity.activityName;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aVSaCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSAttributedString *attString;
    attString = cell.textLabel.attributedText;
    return cell;
}


//     Section Label

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionLabel = [[[frc sections] objectAtIndex:section]name];
    return [sectionLabel uppercaseString];
}

-(void) refreshData
{
    //This was the turning point for proper MR grouping. The two Properties (activityCategory and activityName) are used as Sort descriptors in the underlying core data methods

    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"activityCategory,activityName"
                                  ascending:YES withPredicate:nil
                                    groupBy:@"activityCategory"
                                   delegate:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by simply deleting the TableView and dragging in a new one, wiring it up. The problem is therefore fixed, but I have no idea what caused it.

Thanks to @drhr, who commented, and all others who took a look!

**Edit:**

Just wondering if anyone else has run across this problem. I just had it repeat on another tableview, and had to resolve it as above. FWIW, I'm using Xcode 5, and developing an iPhone app.

I guess fixed is good, but it would be nice to actually know what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Clip Subviews" is selected for that `UITableView` in the Property Inspector, and that the table's `clipsToBounds` is not set to `NO` somewhere in the code.

Comment: Just checked. Clip Subviews is checked. I've never heard of clipsToBounds, and can't find a mention of it in the project.

Comment: Hmm that's the only way I can seem to reproduce that. Could you add any code to your post that relates to or affects the tables? (Particularly `UITableViewDelegate`, and `UITableViewDataSource` too I suppose).

Comment: Is there anything different in the Identity Inspector's "User Defined Runtime Attributes"?  Other than that I'm wondering if ListActivity is doing any funky stuff in an `-init:` method (or one of the other init variants), but that should cause it to happen in both tables.. sounds like it has to be something in IB somewhere I'm just not what else it could be.

Comment: I should maybe have been more patient, but as you can see below, I deleted and replaced the offending tableview. However, I can't imagine how there could have been any User Defined Runtime Attributes, since I know I didn't add anything there. I agree that any weirdness in the store should show up in both tables. In any case, it doesn't seem like the entities or attributes could have any effect on the parameters in the tableview. Thanks again!